# How to use Spring Data for Apache Cassandra with Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-data-cassandra

I have a question about Spring Data REST using with Spring Data Cassandra.

Are these two libraries able to work together? When I try to access the Spring Data REST UR it keeps asking me to provide an id field, however, in my Cassandra table there is no id field at all. I tried to go through the Spring Data REST documentation and it is not clear how to use Spring Data REST along with Spring Data Cassandra.

Consider my table like below:

```
@PirmaryKey
String firstName;
String lastName
```

Then what is my id? Can someone please give me some direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data Cassandra and Spring Data REST work only together if you use a single primary key column annotated with `@Id`. Compound primary keys are not supported by Spring Data REST and they would not map well with a `{entity}/{id}` URI scheme.

Comment: Note, for composite keys you can implement a `BackendIdConverter` to convert your composite `backendId` to/from a string `requestId` suitable for REST URIs.